# QGIS won't start for 'ordinary' Citrix users

Tags: qgis-3, citrix

I've installed ver 3.22 on a Citrix server to publish to users. Opening QGIS from Citrix Workspace works for admin users but appears to stall for ordinary users. There is no error message showing, just nothing displayed on the users screen. I can see an active Citrix session and the exe is running on the server but the application doesn't start for the user.

I'm guessing this is a permissions issue on the server, maybe it's trying to write somewhere it can't.

What actually happens when QGIS starts up?

Comment: Have they read/write permissions on %APPDATA%\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had given them full control over c:\users and I can see that it has written some file to their profile now but it's still not starting.

Comment: You didn't specify how you installed it : packaged installer or OsGeo4W install ?

Comment: I used the packaged installer. It works fine for myself and other admins just not the users

Comment: Maybe you can give a try (if it's not so complicated to configure) with the Osgeo install. There are post install scripts in \OSGeo4W64\etc\postinstall\

Comment: In case anyone else is having this problem with locked down users and machines.
Right click the program file, go to Compatibility troubleshooter and Program require additional permissions.

Comment: You can post the solution as answer, this is even recommanded !